# Navigation drawer is not closing even after closeDrawers()

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am creating a app with navigation drawer which is used to navigate through activities.

Here's my code or drawer

```
private void initInstances() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(busr.this, drawerLayout, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, MainActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, aff.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_3:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, webs.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_4:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, admnActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_5:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, busr.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_6:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, trng.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_7:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, prospct.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_8:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, erp.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_9:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, result.class));
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: use this drawerLayout.closeDrawers(); in your cases when you start the new activity in your like this
                    case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, MainActivity.class));
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
break;

Comment: now i understand what i did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: For closing the `drawerlayout`

```
case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START))
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                    startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, MainActivity.class));
                    break;
```

or

```
case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    startActivity(new Intent(busr.this, MainActivity.class));
                    break;
```

Comment: thanks now i understand i'll your solution then i will updates here

Comment: @noobprogrammer if the answer helped...mark it as correct.